# Writing a class that accepts a callback in Python?

Tags: python, callback

I need to write a class that allows a subclass to set an attribute with the name of a function. That function must then be callable from instances of the class.

For example, I say I need to write a Fruit class where the subclass can pass in a welcome message. The Fruit class must expose an attribute print_callback that can be set.

```
class Fruit(object):
    print_callback = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Fruit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.print_callback("Message from Fruit: ")
```

I need to expose an API that is can be consumed by this code (to be clear, this code cannot change, say it is 3rd party code):

```
def apple_print(f):
    print "%sI am an Apple!" % f

class Apple(Fruit):
    print_callback = apple_print
```

If I run:

```
mac = Apple()
```

I want to get:

> Message from Fruit: I am an Apple!

Instead I get:

> TypeError: apple_print() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

I think this is because self is passed in as the first argument.

So how do I write the Fruit class? Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate the problems you've been having with this approach and the excellent solutions below.  However this looks to me like you should be defining `print_callback` as a method (maybe just called `print_me`, and getting subclasses to override it.  That would be simple and pythonic.  For every different kind of `print_me` method, make a different subclass.

Comment: My motivation for posing the question was that I wanted to subclass Google App Engine's google.appengine.ext.db.djangoforms (e.g. as DF2) to allow override of an attribute formfield_callback in the same manner as Django's ModelForm (django.forms.ModelForm). The idea is that 'class f(DF2)' could then be used by standard Django simply by changing the superclass to django.forms.ModelForm. I don't know why the Django authors defined formfield_callback as an attribute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python assumes that any functions bound within a class scope are methods. If you'd like to treat them as functions, you have to dig around in their attributes to retrieve the original function object:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Fruit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # The attribute name was changed in Python 3; pick whichever line matches
    # your Python version.
    callback = self.print_callback.im_func  # Python 2
    callback = self.print_callback.__func__ # Python 3

    callback("Message from Fruit: ")
```

Comment: Or better yet, just add a `self` argument to the function so it can act like a normal method.

Comment: According to the question, the callback definition cannot be changed.

Comment: BTW, also worth noting is that the `im_func` attribute of methods got renamed to `__func__` in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 6):

You can use directly:

```
class Apple(Fruit):
    print_callback = staticmethod(apple_print)
```

or:

```
class Apple(Fruit):
    print_callback = classmethod(apple_print)
```

In the first case, you'll get only one parameter (the original). In the second, you'll receive two parameters where the first will be the class on which it was called.

Hope this helps, and is shorter and less complex.

Comment: "to be clear, this code cannot change, say it is 3rd party code"

Answer (score 3):

**Updated**: incorporating [abourget's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567777/writing-a-class-that-accepts-a-callback-in-python/1568198#1568198) to use `staticmethod`:

Try this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Fruit, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # Wrap function back into a proper static method
    self.print_callback = staticmethod(self.print_callback)

    # And now you can do:
    self.print_callback("Message from Fruit: ")
```

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for something more like this when I found this question:

```
class Something:
    def my_callback(self, arg_a):
        print arg_a

class SomethingElse:
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback

something = Something()
something_else = SomethingElse(something.my_callback)
something_else.callback("It works...")
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also a bit dirtyer solution with metaclasses:

```
def apple_print(f):
    print "Apple " + f

class FruitMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        func = dct["print_callback"]
        dct["print_callback"]=lambda x,f,func=func: func(f)
        return type.__new__(cls,name,bases,dct)

class Fruit(object):
    __metaclass__ = FruitMeta
    print_callback = None
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fruit,self).__init__()
        self.print_callback("Msg ")

class Apple(Fruit):
    print_callback = apple_print

mac = Apple()here
```

It manipulates the class before its creation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python 3's `__func__` or Python 2 `im_func` to get function object and call it directly.
For global functions it will work ok. But if you want to call function for specific class instance,
you need to provide class instance as first argument to callback function.

Here is example:

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Test1 instance'

    def OnPrint(self, value):
        assert isinstance(self, Test1), 'Wrong self argument type'
        print(f'{self.name}: Test1.OnPrint with value {value}')

t1 = Test1()
f1 = t1.OnPrint.__func__

print('1')
f1(t1, 5)

# Will print:
#     Test1 instance: Test1.OnPrint with value 5
print('2')

#f1(1,2)
#AssertionError: Wrong self argument type

#f1(2)
#TypeError: Test1.OnPrint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

Please note that you can omit `assert isinstance` if you're confident that call is right one.